# Does anyone know this song? Pokèmon XY

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

My little brother was looking an episode of Pokèmon XY and I heard this great melody.
I used audacity to remove the narration voice but neither shazam or midomi could find it.
Anyone can help? https://vocaroo.com/i/s0KbvLpoFFe0

Comment: Has looking up the Pokemon XY anime OST yielded any results?

Answer (score 1):

According to my Shazam, it is `Alexis - Electr3x`.

This is the video that Shazam links to: [Nightstep - Universe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-vw04xN3KM) thought that has a different title and artist name, maybe a re-mix?